# how can link two line in a table with a reference

Tags: sql-server

[image]I'm trying to link 2 row of my table with some reference. If i do a customer order, we have to get 10% as deposit and i have to print a receipt saying XX is the amount and yy is the deposit , so remaining (xx-yy) as balance.

Problem is when i create a order it will create a line in table with type CC and it will have info about actual amount. when i pay deposit it will create  line 2 with type FF and this will not have any detail of item price , but will have detail of amount deposit.

I have a reference in my deposit line 2 "date+type(CC)+store code+ID".

ID of line 1 and 2 is different, now how i can fetch the actual amount

so in the my case, from the image 30-6 = 24

I should show this 24 as a value

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does the order reference span both rows?

Comment: Start by putting together a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can use as a basis for understanding your current situation and for providing suggestions. It is not clear if your question ("show this 24 as a value") is a visual / reporting issue, a schema issue, etc. And please remember that no one knows your schema. Phrases like "create line with type cc" mean nothing to your reader.

Comment: @Fleshy and SMor. Thank you for replaying..